# How an iterable object is iterated without next?

Tags: python, iterator

I've done a research over similar questions on this subject, but didn't find a duplicate.

It is stated that an object is *iterable* if it implements `__iter__` protocol.

> `iterator.__iter__()`:
>   Return the iterator object itself. This is required to allow both containers and iterators to be used with the for and in statements.
>
> `iterator.__next__()`:
>   Return the next item from the container. If there are no further items, raise the StopIteration exception.

From my understanding this applies to all *iterator objects*. I've encountered a code that implements a binary-tree container. The container only has `__iter__` and so does the node objects resides in it.

The `__iter__` implementation of the Node objects returns a *generator*. It yields objects and seems to do **all the logic**, without an implementation of `__next__`.

How this code actually works? It seems to function just as a regular *iterator*, but this one has no `__next__`. Ofcourse if I manually do `iter(obj)` and then `next(obj)` it works. Here is the code snippet:

```
class BinaryCont(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.size = 0

    def __iter__(self):

        class EmptyIter():
            def next(self):
                raise StopIteration

        if self.root:
            return self.root.__iter__()
        return EmptyIter()

class Node(object):

    def __init__(self, val, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def __iter__(self):
        if self.has_left_child():
            for child in self.left:
                yield child

        yield self.val

        if self.has_right_child():
            for child in self.right:
                yield child
```

An example of running code

```
bt = BinaryCont()
bt.insert(5)
bt.insert(3)
bt.insert(7)
for node in bt:
    print node

3
5
7

it = iter(bt)
type(it)
<type 'generator'>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `__iter__` method is a [*generator function*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator), because it uses [`yield`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement) in the function body. A generator function, when called, returns a generator object. It is *that object* that has a `__next__` method.

Your `Node` is not an iterator itself. It is merely an *iterable* object; an iterable object returns a new iterator instance when you call it's `__iter__` method, which is what happens here.

Comment: It is much more clear to me after reading your answer and the *generator function* docs. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

A generator very much does have a `__next__` method. You just don't implement it yourself. A "function" with a `yield` statement does not run your code. It returns an object that runs your code. That object has a `__next__` method.

You may also want to note that there is one other mechanism for making an object iterable: providing `__len__` and `__getitem__` methods. In that case, iteration will occur over the indices from zero to len-1.